# apache users linux

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, password, users

I'm working with Apache on an ec2 box. I'm trying to generate keys for a user, apache on the system.

However, I don't have permission, because it's ec2. So, I sudo - and get asked for a password for sudo apache. I have no password. I can not set a password.

I use keys to access the systems via these users.

How on earth am I meant to generate a key for apache to use?

Answer (score 2):

Keys are associated with users by storing them in the authorized_keys file in the .ssh directory of the user's home folder.

- Generate your key using `ec2-create-keypair`
- Save the private key (and move it off the server)
- Sudo to root (either preface the following commands with `sudo`, or try `sudo -i`) - on Amazon's Linux AMI you do not need a password (I don't know what AMI you are using).
- Append the public key to the `/users/home/folder/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

  - If the `.ssh` folder doesn't exist, create it (`mkdir /users/home/folder/.ssh`) and set permissions to 700.
  - If the file (authorized_keys) does not exist, you can simply move the public key created by ec2-create-keypair to the correct folder (and rename it authorized_keys). Permissions should be set to 600 or less.
  - If there is already an `authorized_keys` file, append to it, using something like `cat ec2_public_key.pub >> /users/home/folder/.ssh/authorized_keys`

The key is associated with the user by virtue of the fact it is within the user's home folder, and accessible only by that user. You may also need to permit SSH access for the specified user in `etc/ssh/sshd_config` as well as to change the shell associated with that user.

Comment: Thanks for this particularly helpful guide. I've certainly got further. But, I'm not constantly getting asked for passphrase, which my normal one doesn't work. Just as a side note, I didn't have a home dir for apache. So have created one and chown'd chmod'd as appropriate - I'm getting further here by trying logged into bash and then php -a > still doesnt seem to work in script. But, I can come to that.

Comment: You shouldn't be asked for a passphrase if you didn't set one - ideally, you should pipe the output of the command directly to file to avoid any stray characters. Also, if you are just trying to setup user accounts on the one machine, you can use `ssh-keygen` instead of the ec2 command (the difference being that the keypair won't be registered with AWS). I don't think you mentioned why you were trying to login as Apache - offhand, it seems like an unusual task.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the manual: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-CreateKeyPair.html

Comment: Hmm, this is for creating a generic key pair. Not one attached to a particular user, no? I mean, I have a pem file it can use. This is coming from the fact that apache user is not able to ssh. Ah I dunno. Round in circles. Thanks.